# How can i get the BSSID of a wifi router I'm connected to using python?

Tags: python, wifi

Can i connect using any python libraries or can someone please tell me how i can implement the commands from commandprompt in python.

Comment: Which platform are you on, Windows or Linux

Comment: Both Windows and Linux provide command line tools to do these network operations.
For Linux Read about `WPA supplicant` and on Windows you can use `netsh`

Once you know what command need to be executed you can executed those using `subprocess` module

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the operating system.

```
from sys import platform
import subprocess
if platform == 'linux' or platform == 'linux2':
    # linux
   output = subprocess.check_output('iwgetid', '-r')
elif platform == 'darwin':
    # OS X
    ps = subprocess.Popen(('/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport', '-I'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = subprocess.check_output(('awk', '/ SSID/ {print substr($0, index($0, $2))}'), stdin=ps.stdout)
elif platform == 'win32':
    output = subprocess.check_output("netsh wlan show interfaces")
    ps.wait()

print output
```

Comment: Thank you so much!.Can you please tell me how to print only the bssid?

Comment: might be that under linux we should pass the arguments as an array, like so `output = subprocess.check_output(['iwgetid', '-r'])`